# Help with UV Unwrapping Modular Triangular Pieces

Tags: texturing, uv

I am creating a modular hill set and have four quarter sections that go together to form a hill. I find that I get the best unwrap when using the Project from view option when looking straight down at the object. However, because my mesh is not a plane with 4 sides but instead a triangle, it unwraps with one side at the UVMap rightside, and it aligns the other side of the triangle with the top. The issue is that textures are seamless from left to right and top to bottom, but never seamless left to top. So i need a way to get one side on the left and the other on the right without major distortion. I am unsure if seems, stitching and splitting could be used to help solve my issue.[image] [image] [image] Thank you very much in advance!!!!

Comment: did u try project from view?

Comment: Yes I've been using project from view in bounds. The issue is I need the sides to be seamless but they will never be seamless unless UV is mapped from left to right. Right now it's the right and the top which many textures are not seamless in this way. So I need a way to manipulate the UVs to accomplish this, likely manually... but my circumstances are alittle unique but ik it's possible.

Comment: BTW, assuming that I figure this all out, once I finish this hill set, I will be giving it away for free (open-source/creative commons) to anyone who wants to throw a quick realistic modular terrain set together for thier purposes

Comment: did u search for "seamless texture blender"? there are tutorials out there and some add-ons....

Comment: Yes the issue is that all the objects can Be mapped to a 4 sidded plane in the tutorials and mine can not as it only has three sides. I could make it have 4 sides but the vertices for the area above the origin will be sharing the same location which isn't really best practice.

Comment: Do you mind up voting this to get other looks. I am on a bit of a deadline and really would like to figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: i would recommend providing a blend file so people can check it out and test solution proposals. An upvote wouldn't help much.